# Use old instance in JUnit test

Tags: java, junit, robotium

I try to use different instances for my tests but the first one is always used.
During the second test, it's the content of the first instance that is displayed.
I don't know where to look for.

```
public class MyActivityTest extends
    ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyActivity> {

private Solo solo;  

public MyActivityTest() {
    super(MyActivity.class);
}

protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    Authentication.setSessionId("mysessionid", this.getInstrumentation()
            .getTargetContext().getApplicationContext());
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
}

public void testFailFetching() {

    CommunicationFactory.setInstance(MyActivityData.FALSE_QUIZCOMM_DEFAULT);

    //some Solo tests

}

public void testSucceedFetching() {

    CommunicationFactory.setInstance(MyActivity.CORRECT_QUIZCOMM_DEFAULT);

    //some Solo tests

}

@Override
protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    CommunicationFactory.setInstance(null);
    super.tearDown();
}
}
```

Comment: Are the return values from `getInstrumentation()` and `getActivity()` going to vary between each test. Otherwise, you are potentially creating an identical `Solo` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setUp()` method will be called before each test. Provided it completes without throwing an exception (which presumably would abort your tests anyway), your `solo` variable is being reconstructed for each test. The follow test code demonstrates this:

```
public class ExampleTest extends TestCase {
  private static int num = 1;

  private Foo foo;  

  @Override
  protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    foo = new Foo(num++);
  }

  public void testA() {
    foo.printNum();
  }

  public void testB() {
    foo.printNum();
  }

  private static class Foo {
    private final int num;

    public Foo(int num) {
      this.num = num;
    }

    public void printNum() {
      System.out.println(num);
    }
  }
}
```

This prints:

```
1
2
```

It's possible the `Solo` objects *equal* each other in the separate tests. But they won't be the *same* object.